# Can Pentaho be hosted in microsoft azure

Tags: azure, pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

Can we host Pentaho data integration in Microsoft azure.If yes what may be the estimated cost for this.

Comment: Yes. you can.
It depends on which version one is using.
if you use community edition then it will be only your Azure costing no cost from pentaho end.

Comment: @WorkingHard..great thanks

Comment: Someone have some reading, article or tutorial about HOW to do it?